# sort with first key only (preserve order for rest)

Tags: sorting, unix, gnu-coreutils

I have a file such as

```
day1 aargh
day2 boom
day3 crack
day2 argh
```

and I want to sort it according to *first* key, but not any other keys, that is, I want to *preserve order* of lines where the key is the same.

I uexpected it will be as simple as

```
$ sort -k1,1 myfile
day1 aargh
day2 aargh
day2 boom
day3 crack
```

but whoops. as you can see, *sort* put the original line 4 before line 2 without any reason, throwing away the original order.  (On day 2. "boom" was before "aargh"--not the other way.  There were no 2 "aargh"s without "boom"! :)).

What I wanted was:

```
$ sort -k1,1 myfile
day1 aargh
day2 boom
day2 aargh
day3 crack
```

Why is that?  Is that a bug?  And more importantly, how to make sort behave the way I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this option:

```
-s, --stable
       stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison
```

The last-resort comparison is a stringwise comparison of the entire line, used if all the keys are equal.

And the next time you have trouble with `sort` (which you definitely will have more trouble if you keep using it; there are many non-intuitive things in it) try using `--debug` to see what is being compared.

If you take just this line:

```
day2 aargh
```

and try `sort --debug -k1,1` on it you should get this:

```
day2 aargh
____
__________
```

The input line is shown with a row of underscores under `day2`. This means `day2` is the highest-priority sort key for that line. It will be compared to the highest-priority sort key of the other lines to decide which one comes first. This key is included in the list of keys because of the `-k1,1`.

The next row of underscores is under the whole line. That means the next sort key for the line in descending priority order is the whole line. If the `-k1,1` key is exactly the same in a pair of lines, this is what will be compared next. This key is included in the list of keys because of the absence of `-s`.

Try it again with `-s -k1,1 --debug` and you'll see the second row of underscores is gone.

I can't think of an example where `sort -k1,1` would behave differently from `sort` with no options, since the whole-line comparison is going to start with the same bytes as the first-field comparison. But surely you can see that `sort -k2,2` has a distinct meaning: first try the second field, then the whole line. So `-k1,1` by itself is kind of a useless degenerate case.

As for *why*... the default behavior of `sort` has included a last-resort whole-line comparison at least as far back as Version 6 UNIX - see [the man page from 1975](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/man/man1/sort.1) which says

> Lines that compare equal are ordered with all bytes significant.

(And there was no `-s` option to disable it either!)

The strange default behavior of `sort` is just a historical thing we have to live with because something that old and widely used can't have its defaults changed. Be thankful for GNU's `--debug` option, a relatively late addition which arrived in 2010.

Comment: Thanks, this was incredibly useful and not at all mentioned in the modern man page.  I find it highly frustrating that `-k1,1` is useless and couldn't for the life of me figure out what was generating that second line in debug mode.  They really need to include information about the last-resort comparison in the modern man page.

Answer (score 1):

Wumpus has already provided the right answer. I tried to add this as a comment but it is too long, so, please do not undervote me :)

> "A pair of lines is compared as follows: sort compares each pair of fields, in the order specified on the command line, according to the associated ordering options, until a difference is found or no fields are left. If no key fields are specified, sort uses a default key of the entire line. Finally, as a last resort when all keys compare equal, sort compares entire lines as if no ordering options other than --reverse (-r) were specified. The --stable (-s) option disables this last-resort comparison so that lines in which all fields compare equal are left in their original relative order. The --unique (-u) option also disables the last-resort comparison." 
>   [sort-invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html)